# Observing AXUIelement's children changes?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, accessibility, accessibility-api

Is it possible to receive notifications if, for a specific parent AXUIelement, any of it's children change (an attributes), or a child is added/removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For added/removed You can get notified if an element is created with NSAccessibilityCreatedNotification (and then check if it has the appropriate parent) and destroyed with NSAccessibilityUIElementDestroyedNotification.  I don't see a [accessibility notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/Accessibility_RoleAttribute_Ref/Notifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007870-Notifications-SW1) for arbitrary attribute changes.